# Find JSON/partial JSON in table

Tags: java, json, postgresql

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

I'm looking through this and I'm not seeing what I am looking for, but what I want to do is this. I have a Java application that generates an object:

```
{"first":"Joe","last":"Doe"}
```

I want to query the database to find json objects with these fields. These fields are NOT static (I could have n fields and they can all be different).

```
select op.*
from bw.people p
where p.object_as_json = '{"first":"Joe","last":"Doe"}' -- this clearly doesn't work
```

**Update**

`object_as_json` is now a `jsonb` data type

One entry in person table, has

```
object_as_json ='{"first":"Joe","last":"Doe","middle":"S","DOB":"1940-01-01"}'
```

My queries were (neither of these returned anything):

```
select *
from bw.people
where object_in_json = '{"last":"Doe","first":"Joe"}'

select *
from bw.people
where object_in_json = '{"first":"Joe","last":"Doe","middle":"S","DOB":"1940-01-01"}'
```

Comment: If that column is JSONB (instead of JSON) then your query should work

Comment: its not jsonb, but let me see if that will work

Comment: JSONB works as it normalizes the values: https://rextester.com/OKFX2550

Comment: So I converted the column to jsonb and tried the query in question. It isn't returning anything. I'll update my question with my query.

Comment: Blah - I missed the jsonb part. So it works, but I cant find partial entries (ie: just first and last instead of all 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `jsonb`, you could write

```
WHERE object_in_json @> '{"last":"Doe","first":"Joe"}`
```

With `json` you'll have to write

```
WHERE object_in_json ->> 'last' = 'Doe'
  AND object_in_json ->> 'first' = 'John'
```